# Can Gantt chart of fusionWidget run without flash player?

Tags: javascript, android, flash, fusioncharts, gantt-chart

My project structure is as:

[image]

I am trying to load a Gantt chart without flash player, but it is not displaying any chart on screen.

and below is code

```
String chartId = "myChartId" + Math.random();
    String html = "<html>"
      + "  <head>"
      + "   <title>Multi Series Step Line Chart</title>"
      + "   <script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='file:///android_asset/Chart/FusionCharts.js'></script>"
      + "   <script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='file:///android_asset/Chart/FusionCharts.HC.Widgets.js'></script>"
      + "   <script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='file:///android_asset/Chart/jquery.min.js'></script>"
      + "   <script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='file:///android_asset/Chart/FusionCharts.HC.js'></script>"
      + "   <script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='file:///android_asset/Chart/FusionCharts.HC.gantt.js'></script>"
      + "   <script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript' src='file:///android_asset/Chart/FusionCharts.jqueryplugin.js'></script>"
      + "  </head>"
      + "  <body>"
      + "   <div id='chartdiv' align='center'>Graph will load here"
      + "  <script type='text/javascript' >"
      + "  FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript') "
      + "       var chart = new FusionCharts('file:///android_asset/Chart/Gantt.swf', '"
      + chartId + "', '1230', '300', '0','1');"
      + "       chart.setXMLUrl('" + getFilesDir()
      + File.separator + "Data.xml" + "');"
      + "       chart.render('chartdiv'); " + "</script>"
      + "   </div>" + "  </body>" + " </html>";
    System.out.println("Html a is " + html);
    WebView web_view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.driver_log);
    WebSettings webSettings = web_view.getSettings();
    webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    web_view.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html,
      "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Are you sure that all the js/css files are loaded properly in to your webview? Can you show your project structure?

Comment: N Bhargav, project structure is as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer the attached sample of using FusionWidgets in an Android native application.

Similarly, you can update this application to render a Gantt chart instead of Angular Gauge.

Also, the PDF may prove to be helpful.

FusionWidget+Android Sample - https://www.dropbox.com/s/tisri8pefjmpei2/FusionWidgets.zip

PDF- How to use FusionCharts with Android Mobile Applications- https://www.dropbox.com/s/pz9772tvobxooel/Android%20Native_How%20to%20use.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot dear FraZer!
You have done s great job, thank u so much.

Comment: Its ok Teekam... :)
Good to know that it helped...write 2 me in case other Queries regarding the Android implementation :)

Comment: Dear FraZer, 
      
Thanks for your support.
Currently i am facing a problem regarding to app is on foreground or background. submitted a question on below link , please have look

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822492/app-crashes-on-bringing-it-to-foreground-in-android

Comment: Dear FraZer please suggest for below question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21845153/why-app-service-restarting-and-not-able-to-restart

Comment: Dear Teekam, It's not clear how you implemented, the problem should not occur normally. Please let me know some more info that may be helpful. Also you may explicitly perform grbge collection before the starting of the service, this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using FusionWidgets XT (v3.3.1) and above for rendering JavaScript variant of the Gantt chart.

Also, ensure `FusionCharts.HC.js`, `FusionCharts.HC.Widgets.js`, `FusionCharts.HC.Gantt.js` and `jquery.min.js` are kept in the same folder as `FusionCharts.js`.

Comment: Sanjukta,
    I am implementing it for android tablet but is is not responding.
    Can you please give me some example?